# Tooltipster appear on right side

Tags: javascript, tooltipster

I would like to get my tool tip to appear on the right of the origin but I seem to be having trouble to get this to do so!.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
<img src="/img/info-gray-26.png" id="shiftclick">
<script>$("#shiftclick").tooltipster({contentAsHTML: true, plugins: ["sideTip"], side:"right", content: "Pro-tip: Shift-click events to create email reminders!"});</script>
```

Any Ideas? I have read the GitHub page but no success!

Comment: Check the use cases of the documentation, it's explained